# Java SecurityManager grant vs grant codebase

Tags: java, java-security, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I am investigating java security manager. I see that 'grant' is required attribute for *.policy file and it is global. But how it will behave in case if I add 'grant codeBase' for the same resoure. For example:

```
    grant codeBase "jar:file:${catalina.base}/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/-" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}/logs/-", "delete";
};

grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}/logs/-", "write";
};
```

1. Will log4j-1.2.17.jar has a permission to delete files in the log folder?
2. Can 'grant codeBase' override 'grant' section?

Thank you!